# How best to integrate PPA into Debian?

Tags: debian, zfs

I'm working with ZFS on Linux, on my Debian squeeze server. I've found a [useful package in an Ubuntu PPA](https://launchpad.net/~zfs-native/+archive/stable), apparently by one of the ZoL developers, and I would like to integrate it into my package system. However, I am really having a terrible time doing this. It seems like it would be possible if I upgraded my system to the testing branch, but I'd prefer not to do this for obvious reasons.

So, what is the One True Way to do this? Or, what is a passable way to do this, i.e. one that does not involve an ice nine-like assimilation of my entire system to testing branch?

Edit: Silly question. I clicked the little green "technical information about this package" on launchpad and all was revealed.

Comment: (+1 for the ice nine reference) If you have solved the problem, please submit and accept your own answer and give some more detail so it can be of benefit to others having the same problem.

Comment: My guess is that you will have to download the source packages and rebuild them for Debian.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool for adding a repository easily (apt-add-repository)[http://blog.anantshri.info/howto-add-ppa-in-debian/]

1. Download file

   $ wget http://blog.anantshri.info/content/uploads/2010/09/add-apt-repository.sh.txt
2. Save this file in /usr/sbin/

   $ cp add-apt-repository.sh.txt /usr/sbin/add-apt-repository
3. Change permissions to execute

   $ chmod o+x /usr/sbin/add-apt-repository
4. Change ownership to root

   $chown root:root /usr/sbin/add-apt-repository
5. Now when ever you need to execute command type

   $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ppa-name